# Disable UIButton in another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uibutton

I'd like to disable an UIButton in a UITableview in another ViewController:

I tried, inside the SecondViewController, but it only disable the _buttonDesc, buttonCell still is enabled:

- buttonCell is the Button inside of UITableView.
- buttonDesc is the Button Comprar, inside the SecondViewController.

.

```
-(IBAction)comprar
{
    [_buttonDesc setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [_buttonDesc setEnabled:NO];
    LivroCell *lvc = [[LivroCell alloc]init];

    [lvc.buttonCell setEnabled:NO];
}
```

[image: "FirstViewController"][image]

Comment: I don't understand how your code relates to the images. Presumably it's an IBAction triggered by the 'Comprar' button in the second viewController. What is '_buttonDesc' and what is a 'LivroCell'?

Comment: You are only instantiating a `LivroCell` and setting it's `buttonCell` to disabled.  It doesn't live anywhere nor do you see it in your UI.  To properly disabled it, you will need to obtain a reference to an **existing** instance of `LivroCell` then disable it like you do.

Comment: @HeWas, _buttonDesc is ComprarButton, LivroCell is a class that create the custom cell of the UITableview.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the actual buttonCell you want to disable. Creating a new instance of LivroCell will not help you.

The easiest way to do this is when someone clicks the "Buy" button, and you create the new UIViewController, pass a reference to the buy button (if "Buy" calls an IBAction then pass sender to the child view controller you create). So make a property on your child view controller to store the button, set that property when you do alloc/init, then it's easy to disable later.